Is integer equation of the form $x_1 + 2x_2 + \ldots + nx_n = k$ solvable with an additional constraint?
I want to find a solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, r)$ in the positive integers if it exists to the following equation:
$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 4x_4 + 5x_5 = 120\cdot r$
with the additional constraint that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3060$ and $r \leq 160$.
Is this solvable without brute forcing? It looks Olympiad-esque. I am wondering what techniques could be utilized. However, it is also asking for a partition of numbers that are multiples of $120$, and from my limited experience in this area, finding partitions is not an easy task.

It looks like the natural question to this problem is to find the number of solutions.


I want to find a solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, r)$ in the positive integers if it exists to the following equation:
$$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 4x_4 + 5x_5 = 120\cdot r$$
with the additional constraint that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3060$ and $r \leq 160$.

Define

$u_1 = x_5.$
$u_2 = x_5 + x_4.$
$u_3 = x_5 + x_4 + x_3.$
$u_4 = x_5 + x_4 + x_3 + x_2.$
$u_5 = x_5 + x_4 + x_3 + x_2 + x_1.$

There is a clear bijection between satisfying ordered $~5$-tuples $~(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)~$ and satisfying ordered $~5$-tuples $~(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5).$
So, the problem is reduced to finding all ordered $~5$-tuples $~(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)~$ that satisfy:

$u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + u_4 + u_5 = 120r ~: ~r \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~r \leq 160.$
$u_5 = 3060 = 60 \times 51.$
$u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5 \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
$u_1 < u_2 < u_3 < u_4 < u_5.$

$~u_5~$ can be eliminated, so that the problem changes to

$u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + u_4 = 60(2r - 51) ~: ~r \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~r \leq 160.$
$u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4 \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
$u_1 < u_2 < u_3 < u_4 < (60 \times 51).$

Personally, I see no elegant way of either listing or enumerating all solutions.  One easy way to generate (many) solutions is to set $~u_i = 60 \times v_i~$ and focus on

$v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4 = (2r - 51) ~: ~r \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~r \leq 160.$
$v_1 < v_2 < v_3 < v_4 < 51.$

Since the minimum value of $~v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4~$ is $~10,~$ you must have that $~r \geq 31.~$
So, one obvious solution is $~(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,r) = (1,2,3,5,31).$

How many solutions do you think there are?

For each value of $r$ the number of solutions is just a particular partition number, which individually has no simple formula (though there's effective recursion, asymptotics, and generating functions; and they can easily be iterated over). The requirement that the total size of the auxiliary partition is a multiple of 60 is fairly bizarre, and I doubt it'll let the summation become anything nice. It could be easily coded, at least.

@Frazer I intentionally duck that question, because of previous experience grappling with the $~u_1 < u_2 < u_3 < u_4~$ constraint.  I agree with the comment of Joshua P. Swanson : the math is going to be convoluted here.

You just want any solution?
Subtract the two to get $0 \cdot x_1 + 1 \cdot x_2 + \cdots + 4 \cdot x_5 = 60 \cdot (2r -  51)$ where now $2r-51 \leq 269$. Note that $x_1$ no longer matters. We may as well take $r=26$ so the right-hand side is $60$, and why not use $x_2=60$, $x_3=x_4=x_5=0$, so we need $x_1 = 3000$.
That is, $(3000, 60, 0, 0, 0, 26)$ works. There are many others.

I asked for positive integer solutions, but this is still helpful to anyone reading

Fair enough, I suppose the title just said "integer." The same technique gives positive solutions with no difficulty, e.g. $(3006, 51, 1, 1, 1, 26)$.
